# Append generics with Omit in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to set default properties using `Omit<>` in typescript and append more via generics.

For example, I want to exclude a set of properties by default and have the user choose more to exclude by using `Omit<>`

```js
type OmittedEntity<TEntity extends IBaseEntity, TExtraOmissions extends (keyof TEntity) | void = void> = TExtraOmissions extends keyof TEntity ? Omit<TEntity, "id" | "collection" | TExtraOmissions> : Omit<TEntity, "id" | "collection">

interface IBaseEntity {
    id: string;
    collection: string;
    status: string;
}

// My new Entity
interface ISomeEntity extends IBaseEntity {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    middle: string;
}
```

When trying to exclude one more property than `OmittedEntity<>` does, every works perfectly

```js
const e: OmittedEntity<ISomeEntity, "firstName"> = {
    lastName: "",
    middle: "",
    status: ""
}
```

When trying to exclude two or more properties than `OmittedEntity<>` does, I do not get the desired result.  Typescript wants me to choose between omitting `firstName` or `lastName`

```js
const e: OmittedEntity<ISomeEntity, "firstName" | "lastName"> = {
    lastName: "", // Error
    firstName: "", // Error
    middle: "",
    status: ""
}
```

How to I get the above example to allow me to exclude both properties, not one or the other?

I essentially want

```js
const e: OmittedEntity<ISomeEntity, "firstName" | "lastName"> = {
    middle: "",
    status: ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the distributivity of the conditional type.

```
type OmittedEntity<
  TEntity extends IBaseEntity, 
  TExtraOmissions extends (keyof TEntity) | void = void
> = [TExtraOmissions] extends [keyof TEntity] ? Omit<TEntity, "id" | "collection" | TExtraOmissions> : Omit<TEntity, "id" | "collection">
```

Without the square brackets, the elements in `TExtraOmissions` will be distributed to several `Omits`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2MCATAogO2EkAeAKCigBUsdQoIAPFTVAZygEkAhAQwYnNwBooipdLQBO7eAgYMEAe0xMadRlAAUAawggZAMyHZcASigAfKADcZCVFAC85y6gIA+W1ADaZUeMRTZ8gLpUtBD0TG4aWrpk+qCBAPywiMB40RQg-ABEVhkmUBkAxjIANkUQ+ThyOaaewGISvnIMLgBciUgpPKCZ2bkFxaXlfhlOBKMECNgQItrs+dBsnNwxIFAA3oLEVq0MtRMA5gDcG1CFJWUVmNu7mIfHO+zAAK4MVyL7RwC+owD031AAsitMBAAO5QTogcaTaazeYAZRkcCWaSCSiYCy4ELWx20CBEOwAcuwka93scipxgESSVAdm8bkdiMREKhUKVSQyCF8CIV5MAqK0JMg0BC8MwEUiIZlcfiqcSIMNXOsmVAKYT5a0MhleMcWWyIJrtXdgA9noauWNQJBSABGVxClAYZZiiXIvh5GXqpFVPJquXekY8xr87SCpKO0XixFuroevFehW9P3UhUuOzKpnJjV5bVQX7gkQiGQiHHx-0GnP8fPoQvF3VWfWGnUq+5PF45rlAA)

---

Also, you could simplify the whole `OmmitedEntity` type to this:

```
type OmittedEntity<
  TEntity extends IBaseEntity, 
  TExtraOmissions extends (keyof TEntity) = never
> = Omit<TEntity, "id" | "collection" | TExtraOmissions>
```

I don't see any benefit of using `void` here. We can just set the default to `never`, so if no type is given this will be ommitted from the union.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  Using `void` was my attempt to set a default value if users didn't supply a generic.  Good to know about `never`